# Sitecore: Other than the Sitecore Calendar Module, what advanced Calendar solutions are people using?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, calendar, sitecore, google-calendar-api

The Sitecore Calendar Module doesn't have the features that we want: recurring events, multiple calendar integration, event notifications.

My team is looking at 3rd party solutions and is thinking seriously about JQueryUI front-end, in-house business layer, and Google Calendar API back-end. Before jumping in with the Google solution, what other implementations have teams been working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are rolling our own using similar technologies, however, we are using the Sitecore tree as a data store and [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) as the front-end.

We decided on using the tree so that we could utilize Sitecore's pipeline model to schedule tasks, reminders, and automate publish/un-publishing of events. Plus it is a familiar environment for our content authors.

[DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) takes care of .ICS generation pretty well.

One hurdle was handling timezones properly in Sitecore which automatically assumes the timezone of the CM server. We ended up creating a custom `Droplist` field that pulls in Windows' timezones in the form of `TimeZoneInfo`s.

Whatever you decide, I'm interested to hear how things progress. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, Derek. Sorry, for the delayed response. We ended up using DayPilot as our calendar/scheduler component along with the existing Event template from the Sitecore Calendar module. DayPilot uses a very simple schema, and we were able to fit everything in the existing Event template, except for the recurrence field (which contains nicely serialized recurrence information). Basically, we store events in one folder, named by date... very clean and simple implementation for our purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I recently grabbed the Sitecore Calendar module Shared Source project and complied it against the Sitecore 7.0 DLLs. I got it running but the Javascript library it uses (Prototype.js) conflicts with jQuery 1.9.1 which we use quite heavily in our website projects.

I have since given up on the Sitecore Calendar and am investigating integrating with either FullCalendar or DayPilot. Can you provide any update on progress with integrating these controls? Dare I ask... is any GitHub code samples available so that we too don't need to re-invent this wheel?

As an aside, I am dissapointed in Sitecore R&D for not offering better 'out of the box' solutions for this. I'm finding their CMS is great for ground up "empty canvas" website projects but not for portal type projects and I'm trying my best not to resort to a SharePoint solution.